# Can flutter firebase auth tackle multiple social media accounts with same email id?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

Does firebase auth help tackle same email id account issue?

For ex. say I am using firebase auth in my flutter app. I have Facebook and Gmail of same email. 1st I create account with Gmail, logout and then 2nd time I try to create account with facebook which has same email ID. Then is firebase designed to give me some type of error message saying "**user with this email has already logged in with gmail**" and vice-versa ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can configure whether users can create multiple accounts that use the same email address, but are linked to different sign-in methods. For example, if you don't allow multiple accounts with the same email address, a user cannot create a new account that signs in using a Google Account with the email address ex@gmail.com if there already is an account that signs in using the email address ex@gmail.com and a password.

Please find the details [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820?hl=en&ref_topic=6386702).

Answer (score 0):

No, Firebase won't throw any error, instead it will create a new account for the second sign-in provider. As Both Sign-In providers are different i.e one is facebook and other is google in your example.

If you really want to create a single account for multiple providers.Then you will need to link multiple providers to an single account.

Checkout Firebase official documentation for the instructions to achieve this on android:-

[Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking)